# Amazon MWS Subscriptions API - Price Changes

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

My company is currently using the Amazon MWS Feeds API to make price updates to merchandise via SubmitFeed.  Our issue is with the current throttling, we can only make price changes 4 times / hour.  We received a tip from another organization that suggests we can use the Subscription API to update our pricing 2 times / second.  Is this possible?  What enumeration would we use to do this via Subscription API?  From what I can see, you cannot "send" data using Subscription API, only GET pretty much. I do see where you can UpdateSubscription but it looks like that is only for enabling/disabling the subscription?  Any help would be much appreciated!  I am not a developer, just doing some R&D to help improve our tool, but I can do my best to provide any follow up details.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The [AnyOfferChanged](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/subscriptions/Subscriptions_NotificationType.html) is the enumeration from the [Subscriptions API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/subscriptions/Subscriptions_Overview.html), but yes, that is read only.  You'll get your price changes sent to Amazon SQS in near-real time and in response to those, you can update MWS using a feed and the [SubmitFeed](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_FR/feeds/Feeds_SubmitFeed.html) operation.  The SubmitFeed link shows you ways to maximize performance but you should be able to make more than 4 price changes an hour.  I update anywhere from 10 SKU's to a few hundred every 5 minutes around the clock.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much for the clarification and your time! I just got feedback from our developer and he is saying that we receive the following message when we attempt to make more than 4 price changes in a 60 minute window:
  
**Request from Request for type Feed was metered. Feed creation request for merchant xxxx is metered due to exceeding limit of 4 per 60 minutes. There have been 4 requests of this type in that timeframe.**
  
Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've never encountered a restriction like that.  The throttling limits are much higher than that, according to their docs and my experiences.  You might have to contact MWS support for clarification.  Maybe it's some type of account restriction. https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html